# Can I change story mode choices made in KOTFE / KOTET by replaying?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

As the question states.

Can I go back and replay chapters in Story Mode and alter the outcome of later ones?

Spoilers below

> Let's say I made the decision to save Torian instead of Vette but I later regret that choice.

Or

> Or if I decided to release Valkorion's father's spirit but I decided he would be quite handy to have around for the final stand-off against Vailyn

I've noticed that the choices I make by playing through the chapters again on Veteran Mode has no effect on anything - these chapters just play "one by one".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, replays do not affect the decisions you made the first time around.  Ostensibly, this is because even a small change could invalidate the whole tree of later decisions, and they have not spent the time to add an option that would completely wipe out everything you did later.  I'd suspect this is something of a user experience decision too since there are undoubtedly people who would ignore any warnings and reset, and then regret it.

So if you want to make different decisions "for real", you have to create a new character.

Comment: I pretty much thought as much. I had a small hope based on the fact that nothing would really get destroyed by resetting the campaign, as you can't really make any choices that affects anything beyond just the companions you have available in the end; and certain activities would be out of bounds for a short while (Star Fortresses and so on). But thanks :-)